# Alternative to using wildcards in Replace function (MS Access 2016)

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I migrated a large data set from excel to access. There is one field that needs to be cleaned. Here is an example.

"group: xxxxx, name: keepthisstring1, group: yyyyy, name: keepthissting2, group: zzzzzzz, name: keepthisstring3"

I only want to keep the parts that comes after "name:" so that when cleaned it would look like "keepthisstring1, keepthisstring2, keepthisstring3."

I can do a find and replace using wildcards... Find: "group:*name: "

but there are too many records to use Find and Replace. From what i can tell I can't using wildcards in the Replace function.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: You might have used some script to migrate the data (Python, Tcl, bash etc.) -- if it's possible to import the data into Access again, it might be much easier do this on that import script. I usually pre-clean the data before moving it to the DB: gives more scope to experiment/fine-tune the data cleanup.

Comment: thx... But I'm importing the data via Linked Tables.  So I'm trying to avoid cleaning before importing.

Comment: Why do you say there are too many records for the Find/Replace dialog? Write a VBA function that will parse the string then concatenate the desired parts.

Comment: The database has over 300,000 records.  Find/Replace crashes with that.